# Weird Condition Checks

Tags: c, while-loop, conditional-statements

Let's consider the following C code snippet.

```
while(!var_can_be_0_or_1 && foo_returns_0_or_1(arg1, arg2)) {
     body;
}
```

it's a simple while condition statement which does what I am failing to understand. But let's say I have two macros

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
```

Can someone please tell me(or rather explain to me) what are we checking under the condition in this while loop here? I mean in what condition/s the loop body will execute and in which condition/s it will skip?

**Elaboration**

I found it in a book about Data Structures in a program which converts an infix expression string into a postfix one. The exact code was something like this --->

```
int prcd(char char);
int und, outpos;
char symb, topsymb;

 while(!und && prcd(topsymb, symb)) { <----- Stuck on this one real bad
            postr[outpos++] = topsymb;
            popandtest(&opstk, &topsymb, &und);
 }
```

The elaboration is probably unnecessary but just to put things into context. 
;)

EDIT :

I'm really sorry if the question was somewhat unclear to people who are trying to help, so I'll explain a little bit more about what I am really asking here

Let's forget the code I wrote in the elaborate portion of this text and go back to the first one and let's just say we have a while loop , plain and simple while loop

```
while(!condition1 && condition2) {
execute some codes;
}
```

Here, `condition1` = `und`, und is an int whose value can be either 0 or 1(and NOTHING ELSE). 0 and 1 are macroed to `FALSE` and `TRUE` respectively. And `condition2` = `prcd(topsymb, symb)` ; it's a function whose prototype is mentioned as `int prcd(char char);`. Again it returns either 0 or 1 and NOTHING ELSE.

Now what I want to know is *how* the condition inside the `while` loop brackets gets evaluated.

Hope this clears things up. :)

Comment: `I want to know is how the condition inside the while loop brackets gets evaluated. Hope this clears things up.` - No it doesn't clear things up. The answer is still the same as before. Everything inside the while-loop is "evaluated" if, and only if, the conditions are met.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen My dear sir, ofcourse your answer remains the same. I merely did some edit for people who are having trouble understanding the question. But you knew exactly what I was asking in the first place. Thanks again :)

Comment: If condition1 and condition2 are: 1,0 or 1,1 -- only condition1 is evaluated, and the loop doesn't execute; 0,0 -- both conditions are evaluated, but the loop doesn't execute; 0,1 -- both conditions are evaluated, and the loop does execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I mean in what condition/s the loop body will execute and in which
>   condition/s it will skip

`body` will execute if `var_can_be_0_or_1` is `false` (i.e. `0`) AND the return value of the function `foo_returns_0_or_1` is `true` (i.e. not `0`).

If either criteria are not met then `body` will be skipped.

Comment: ...though it's also important to note that `foo_returns_0_or_1()` won't be called if `var_can_be_0_or_1` isn't zero.

Comment: @Dmitri: Correct but not relevant to the question.

Comment: Thanks @Sani SIngh Huttunen, exactly the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure if this is what you are looking for, but here is what I believe you want:

```
while(!var_can_be_0_or_1 &&    // if this is '0', continue; else exit
      foo_returns_0_or_1(a, b) // if this is NOT '0', continue; else exit
```

Does this help?

Using your macros, this is similar to writing

```
while (var_can_be_0_or_1 == FALSE && foo_returns_0_or_1 == TRUE)
```

I say similar because, if the function  `foo_returns_0_or_1` does NOT return a 1, but instead returns some other number, then your TRUE macro will not match, and the condition test will fail, as written above.

C does not require you to write the equality (== TRUE), but rather can evaluate on the output of the function or the state of the variable, if it is an int, and is the better choice for this statement.

As @John Bode notes, if the first condition fails, then the second condition will never be tested. Since this is a function, then it is possible that the function will never be called.

Comment: Does this include the !?. I say no.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I cringe when I see things like `x == TRUE` in C... since `x` can still evaluate as true when `x == TRUE` does not (in general, not when `x` can only be 0 or 1).

Comment: I agree, @Dmitri. I just included it to potentially make things VERY clear. It is good to note that it probably shouldn't be used unless you are ABSOLUTELY certain that only 0 or 1 will be the result.

Comment: What "this" is ambiguous. if this is !var_can_be_0_or_1 then your comment is wrong. if it is var_can_be_0_or_1 then you are Ok.

Comment: Ah. The way I interpreted this is that there is a var that can be 0 or 1, meaning that if it is 0, then the ! negates that. I think this agrees with the separate code listed in the OP's question. However, I see your point, I think. If the test is indeed !(var is allowed to be 0 or 1), then a 1 or a 0 would pass, whereas a 2 would not for this var. However, I do not think this is the intent of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` operator forces left-to-right evaluation. `!var_can_be_0_or_1` will be fully evaluated (and any side effects applied); if the result of the expression is non-zero (true), then `foo_returns_0_or_1(arg1, arg2)` will be evaluated.  If the result of that expression is also non-zero (true), then the body of the loop will be executed, otherwise the loop will exit.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is some pseudo code with missing pre conditions, because it won't compile as is.

1. if 'und' is global then it must be initialized to zero and the while loop will always be TRUE, if inside function this must be initialized with garbage because it is allocated on stack and hence the behavior is unpredictable.
2. Similarly, missing definition of prcd(), it is hard to suggest what it returns.

I think your need to correct the question with proper inputs.

Comment: sorry, guess my question was unclear in the first place, i'll edit it.